# Promise-based HTTP abstraction layer

Tags: javascript, http, typescript, promise

I am currently working in a project based on a microservices architecture pattern.
Services are wired up by HTTP calls. They eventually call each others for fetching or putting some data.

I am working on the web page which envelops the whole microservices. I mean, the web page actually needs to send and retrieve data from all the services (except one).
There are several times where the web page behaves as a broker, *i.e.:*

> *Fetch some data from service 1,
>
>   fetch some data from service 2.
>
>   Send something to service 3 based on previous responses.*

That's why I decided to implement some functions to avoid lots of duplicated code chunks. This is what I call the **promise-based HTTP abstraction layer**.

I am developing the web page in Typescript, by the way.

I want to mention what my `request` function is. The `request` function performs HTTP requests, unsurprisingly.
It is an [*axios*](https://github.com/axios/axios) call wrapper. However, for the sake of simplicity, since it is not that important I'll show only the header.

```
type HttpMethod = 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'PATCH' | 'DELETE';
declare function request<TResult>(method: HttpMethod, url: string, body?: any): Promise<TResult>;
```

And, for comfort, I declared its prefixed argument different calls

```
const get = request.bind(this, 'GET');
const post = request.bind(this, 'POST');
// And so on ...
```

But I refactored this to take profit of the `request` type argument

```
const get = <TResult>(url: string, body: any) => request<TResult>('GET', url, body);
const post = <TResult>(url: string, body: any) => request<TResult>('POST', url, body);
// And so on ...
```

And, a `waitAll` function which requests to call the URLs passed in and returns a single `Promise` which will be resolved whenever all the requests are done.

```
interface HttpRequest<TResult> {
    url: string;
    request: (url: string, body?: any) => Promise<TResult>;
    body?: any;
};
const waitAll = (...reqs: HttpRequest<any>[]): Promise<any[]> =>
    Promise.all(reqs.map(req => req.request(req.url, req.body)));
```

With this, I can do something like

```
(async () => {
    const req1: HttpRequest<FirstResponse> = {
        url: `http://example.com/one`,
        request: post,
        body: {
            id: 9,
            data: [`hi`, `there`]
        }
    };
    const req2: HttpRequest<SecondResponse> = {
        url: `http://example.com/one`,
        request: get
    };

    const results = await waitAll(req1, req2);
    const [r1, r2] = results;

    const body = { ...r1, ...r2 };
    const finalResponse = await post<ThirdResponse>(`http://example.com/three`, body);

    // do something w/ final response
})();
```

This is working but I notice some wrong things.
It feels weird the `HttpResponse<>` object, that wraps the `url` and the `body` that, in fact, will be called inside its own `request` property function.
And when I call `waitAll`, I'd expect my `r1` and `r2` to be of the matching type (I mean, `r1` must be 
 of type `FirstResponse`, and `r2` must be of type `SecondResponse`) just like `finalResponse` is of type `ThirdResponse`.

I am pretty sure there are lots of improvements to achieve a better-looking API and, the most important thing, take profit of Typescript type safety.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you're right about `HttpRequest` and the oddness of having to pass manually `body` and `url` .

To improve the code, I would suggest to chose a programming paradigm, and to stick to it:

example in OOP:

```
class HttpRequest<TResult> {
    constructor(private method: HttpMethod, private url: string, private body?: any) {}
    request():Promise<TResult> {
        return request(this.method, this.url, this.body); 
    }
};

const req1  = new HttpRequest<FirstResponse>('POST', `http://example.com/one`, {
    id: 9,
    data: [`hi`, `there`]
  });
const req2 = new HttpRequest<SecondResponse>('GET', `http://example.com/one`);

// you now just have to call req1.request() for example , without parameters
```

in more FP friendly way of doing thing:

```
function my_request<T>(httpReq: HttpRequest) {
    return  (): Promise<T> => request(httpReq.method, httpReq.ufl, httpReq.body)
}

const req1  = my_request<FirstResponse>({method:'POST', url:`http://example.com/one`, body:{
    id: 9,
    data: [`hi`, `there`]
});
const req2 = my_request<SecondResponse>({method:'GET', url:`http://example.com/one`});


// you now just have to call req1() for example , without parameters
```

Now, we can improve the typing of `waitAll` with [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), for example for the OOP version (it's equivalent for the FP one):

```
function waitAll<T extends any[]>(...reqs: {[K in keyof T]: HttpRequest<T[K]>}): Promise<T> {
  // the any here is mandatory as Promise.all doesn't support (yet) the above signature
  return Promise.all(reqs.map(req => req.request())) as any;
}

// result type will be a [FirstResponse, SecondResponse]
const result = waitAll(req1, req2)
```

Now, you should ask yourself if you're not "over-abstracting". A code like that:

```
const req1 = request('POST', `http://example.com/one`, {id: 9});
const req2 = request('GET', `http://example.com/one`);

const [r1, r2] = await Promise.all(req1, req2);

const finalResponse = await request('POST', `http://example.com/three`, body);
```

uses only standard TS stuffs (`await`, `Promise.all`), hence is often easier to read for a developper that didn't write the code.

Comment: Hi, @Molochdaa. The idea of the mapped types for keeping the typed-member array is fantastic; never thought about it. However, I must point out the `as any` in its implementation seems quite dirty. `as Promise<T>` is allowed and it feels cleaner. On the  other hand, wrapping the `HttpRequest<>` into an object makes sense for the use of the scoped `this`.

Comment: Finally, I don't really agree with the last statement you said. Note that `Promise.all` is no longer keeping the type response anymore. Moreover, I want (even need) to declare request without invoking 'em instantly, which does `request` function. So instantiating objects seems look to me. Anyways, good approach, I really like the idea. Thanks

Comment: If you want lazy Promise, can you also try something like (would be the same with a  class or a function): 

`type LazyPromise<A> = {request: () => Promise<A>};`

   `function waitAll<T extends any[]>(t: {[K in keyof T]: LazyPromise<T[K]>}): 
    LazyPromise<T> {
        return {request: () => Promise.all(t.map(p => p.request()))} as LazyPromise<T>;
   }`
 
`Promise.all` type should keep the type of the request... up to a certain number (maybe 7 or 8 promises? ) . The different variants for pair, triplet, 4-tuple, etc. are hardcoded in TypeScript lib.d.ts